# SharePoint Online encrypting specific team sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, team-sites

I would like to have specific team sites to require encryption of files without having that requirement for every site; is it possible to encrypt specific team sites only?

Comment: Microsoft stores the data encrypted at rest and encrypted in transit, what else are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

No that's not possible because we dont have those options available to select.

But you may consider implementing **data loss protection policies** via [https://protection.office.com](http://https:protection.office.com) under threat managerment section to have more stringent/specific rules for selected sites/site collections.